# SQL Azure database connection issue

Tags: sql-server, azure

My problem is, I am getting below error when I try to connect the SQL Azure database by using SQL authentication from the Azure VM. The problem is interesting because I can connect same database from different Azure VM. SQL Server has a firewall and both VM IP addresses are whitelisted. I tried to make tcpping to SQL destination from both VM works fine. Unfortunately, I don't have access to grab the azure diagnostic log from the destination SQL Server. Does anyone have any clue what could be the problem?

Error message:

> Cannot open server "XXXXXX" requested by the login. The login failed.

Comment: Those two VMs are in the same VNET? If not, then double check the NSG rules (outgoing). Proabably 1433 is not allowed in the one which is troubling you?

Comment: Have you  switched the `Allow Azure Services and resources to access this server` to ON? if you set the configuration, Azure service can directly access the service.

Comment: Hi @arif, did you solve the error?

Comment: Yes, I was able to resolve the issue by moving VM to another vnet. It was using private IP even though it has public IP, I believe because of subnet service endpoint configuration

Comment: @arifcoskun congratulations that you resolved the issue! I help you post it as answer, then others could know it. You can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Congratulations that you resolved the issue:

"Yes, I was able to resolve the issue by moving VM to another vnet. It was using private IP even though it has public IP, I believe because of subnet service endpoint configuration"

I help you post it as answer and this can be beneficial to other community members.